# Wordpress site on AWS not connecting properly to the DB when using multiple wp hosts

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am having issues with a Wordpress architecture on AWS when using more than one Wordpress server.

I follow this procedure, which basically creates a mysql RDS with one EC2 instance (which has wordpress) that connects the DB:

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/deploy-wordpress-with-amazon-rds

It connects well, I can log in the Wordpress admin page, and also to the demo page.  Now, when I add an extra wp host (ec2 instance) that connect to the same db, that second instance loads the site OK when using its public IP, but two things happen after that, hopefully one of you know why?:

1) When I try to connect to the second instance, specifically the admin page (http://second_instance_ip/wp-admin/) it gets redirected to the other wp host (initial instance), I mean the IP changes to the other host.

2) If I stop the wp first instance that I setup and bring it back then none of the instances connect again properly, showing this:

[Output trying to connect after reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAfIG.jpg)

The following is a Cloudformation template that I wrote that builds the same and shows the same behaviour:

https://github.com/carloshz4/sandbox/blob/master/multiple_wp.yml

If you knew why these behaviours and let me know it'll be much appreciated. Or if you have ever built a HA Wordpress site on AWS that is not affected if any of the hosts goes down (which is the purpose of HA) and could share it for reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the DB the sites address is the first IP, but thats not your issue... If you have multiple instances, you need a load balancer to direct traffic between them.

Comment: Not an wordpress expert, but wouldn't the use of different salt values for same wordpress application lead to some strange behavior? You have two instances with their own salt values, but same database.

Comment: Thanks @hephalump.  Yes I've done it with a Load Balancer but get the same and even some other weird behaviours. I mean, as long as the instance that connected via mysql (command) and created the DB user (the one that goes into wp-config.php) is up and running then things are good. The problem is when it is stopped or rebooted, it breaks.   I am curious about your comment regarding "sites address of the first IP", I wonder if there's a fixed link/dependency between one of the instances and the DB.

Comment: Thank you @Marcin. It worth checking all possible options.  I'll have a look, hadn't thought of that.